# Newer scaladoc with older scala compiler?

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

Is it possible to use scaladoc from trunk without any problems on Scala code written for 2.8.1? I ask because scaladoc in trunk supports some additional tags that are unimplemented in scaladoc in 2.8.1.

I don't anticipate any problems, but I just wanted to check.

If so, how can this be done from sbt?

Comment: Update: It seems to work, although because it actually does typechecking, it may find subtle issues that the old compiler didn't. And I don't know how to do it from sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaladoc is based on the tree parsing performed by the compiler even if it doesn't take everything into account (for exemple what is inside a function isn't important). So, as there were no major changes (and that most of the changes are adds, not deletes) in declaration of functions, objects... You should not have any problem.

In fact, to be clear, it is not the compiler which is applied but the parser.

Don't hesitate to correct me if I am wrong.